# How to change the law to raise the age of a minor from 18 to 21?

Tags: united-states, international, minor, power-of-attorney, age

How would the age of a minor be raised now that higher education is a must. What the legislative procedure is to raise the age of minority?

Alternatively, could a parent show that the child is incompetent and keep them at home legally for a couple more years to get them through high school?

Comment: What you are talking about is guardianship (in the US) and usually requires you to demonstrate that the individual is incapable of making their own decisions. They are still legally an adult, you just have decision-making power over them. You can't just say "my son Billy is a bit of a slacker and I want to have guardianship to make him go to school", guardianship usually requires extenuating circumstances (disability/mental illness).

Comment: @RonBeyer is this better?

Comment: I'm not sure it is... Are you asking what the legislative procedure is to raise the age of minority? Or are you asking if a parent can (legally) consider a child a minor until the age of 21? I'm not sure how the "higher education" thing comes in, many insurance plans and tax deductions for children still work as long as the child is enrolled full-time in school, they go away after they leave college or hit the age of 25 typically.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes to the first and I'm not to worried about the second. revised question again sorry.

Comment: You'll need to pick a jurisdiction, but I don't think the concept of "raising the age of majority for a person" exists anywhere.

Comment: How is higher education a "must"?

Comment: Your profile shows you live in the US, high school ends when your 18, unless you're held back. I don't understand what would be the goal in doing this? The only responsibilities that an 18-year-old have to follow in the US are signing up for eligibility to be drafted and jury duty, even on the tax side of things partners can still claim children older than 18 as a dependent (if the parent supplies half of the child's income).

Comment: It seems to me the answer is the same as for any other proposed change in the law: you convince your legislature to introduce a bill, and to vote it into law through the usual process for that jurisdiction (including approval by the president / governor / queen as appropriate).  My guess is that politically, there is no chance they would be interested in doing so, but that is for Politics.SE instead of this site.

Comment: For the US and its states, you might note that every citizen over 18 is guaranteed the right to vote, under the [Twenty-Sixth Amendment to the US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-sixth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).  So even if the age of majority were raised by statute, 18 to 21-year-olds would still be able to vote, and I'd guess at the next election, they would express their displeasure with those elected officials who supported the measure.  As such, I think it'd be hard for such a measure to find political support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about political process, not the law or legal process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age of majority (age at which a person ceases to be a minor) used to be 21 in most US states. It was lowered to 18 by statutes in various states at various times -- the Vietnam War had a major political effect on this. As the comment by Nate Eldredge says, the right to vote at at 18 is guaranteed by the 26th amendment to the US Constitution. It is possible, but seems unlikely, for a particular state legislature to return the age to 21 by law, at any time for all rights except for voting, or for specified rights. For example, in many states the right to purchase alcohol is only granted at age 21.

If a child is incompetent in a legal sense, one can apply for Guardianship and a judge will evaluate the situation and make an order of Guardianship if the Judge believes it justified. This is normally used only for serious mental illness or disability, or other condition which makes the child (or adult ward) unable to function in society without help, and unable to make decisions in his or her own best interest. The guardian must make regular reports to the court, in most cases. The detailed law of guardianship varies from state to state.

Answer (score 1):

Bills on any subject are all passed the same way.

Here's a video to explain the process of passing a bill into a law:

[I'm Just a Bill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFroMQlKiag)